# Animate levels of elements

Tags: jquery, animation

[image]

I'm trying to make a very simple and short animation with jQuery .

There is a ul list of keywords, structured with parents and children .
The animation should show the first level of elements, then the second level and the third level .

Someone told me there are also CSS3 solutions for this and I don't know what road to take .. any thoughts ?

thanks..

UPDATE :

At this time i have only something like this :

```
<style>
.first {float:left; width:168px; height:68px; background:blue; position:absolute; }
.second {float:left; width:120px; height:32px; background:blue; position:absolute; }
.third {float:left; width:90px; height:26px; background:blue; position:absolute; }
.fourth {float:left; width:auto; height:20px; background:blue; position:absolute; }

.alfa {float: left; width:168px; height:68px; background:blue;}
.beta {float:left; width:120px; height:32px; background:blue; }
.omega {float:left; width:90px; height:26px; background:blue;  }
.orion {float:left; width:auto; height:20px; background:blue;  }

.positiona { margin-left:330px; margin-top:20px; }
.positionb { margin-left:180px; margin-top:50px; }
.positionc { margin-left:280px; margin-top:110px; }
.positiond { margin-left:140px; margin-top:100px; }
.positione { margin-left:180px; margin-top:160px; }
.positionf { margin-left:20px; margin-top:105px; }
.positiong { margin-left:60px; margin-top:140px; }

.positionz { margin-left:0px; margin-top:20px; }
.positionx { margin-left:20px; margin-top:50px; }
.positionv { margin-left:-190px; margin-top:110px; }
.positionn { margin-left:-40px; margin-top:100px; }
.positionm { margin-left:-110px; margin-top:160px; }
.positionl { margin-left:40px; margin-top:105px; }
.positionk { margin-left:20px; margin-top:20px; }
</style>

        <div style="width:505px; float:left;">
            <div class="first positiona">agenius</div>

            <div class="second positionb">echilibru</div>
            <div class="second positionc">planificare</div>

            <div class="third positiond">evolutie</div>
            <div class="third positione">actiune</div>

            <div class="fourth positionf">monitorizare</div>
            <div class="fourth positiong">concepte</div>
        </div>
            <!-- +++++++++++++++++++++ --> 
        <div style="width:505px; float:right;">            
            <div class="alfa positionz">agenius</div>

            <div class="beta positionx">echilibru</div>
            <div class="beta positionv">planificare</div>

            <div class="omega positionn">evolutie</div>
            <div class="omega positionm">actiune</div>

            <div class="orion positionl">monitorizare</div>
            <div class="orion positionk">concepte</div>
        </div>
```

and it looks like this :
[image]

Comment: yes, sorry . code added

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example of how to fade in using CSS3...

http://codepen.io/jcreamer898/pen/Dpdlv

The scss (sass with compass) is...

```
.first, .second, .third {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  @include transition(all 1s ease-in-out);
  opacity: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display:inline-block;
}

.first {
  @include transition-delay(.5s);
  background-color: red;
}

.second {
  @include transition-delay(2s);
  background-color: blue;
}

.third {
  @include transition-delay(3.5s);
  background-color: green;
}

.animate {
  div {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

The first, second, and third, classes all start out with 0 opacity. The `transition all 1s ease-in-out` basically means when any property changes, make sure it takes 1 full second for the change`. Then when an`animate`class is added to the wrapping div, the opacity will change to`1`for all of the divs. The`transition-delay` on each of the divs will change at what point each group fades in.

With a markup structure of...

```
<div id="animation">
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="first"></div>

  <div class="second"></div>
  <div class="second"></div>

  <div class="third"></div>
  <div class="third"></div>
</div>
```

Then kick off the animation with a bit of JS and voila!

```
document.getElementById('animation').className = 'animate';
```

Comment: I tried to make something similar but I can't get it to work ..

http://codepen.io/hanisnl/pen/AEaIe